# UnexpectedValueException in Route.php line 639: Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController]

Tags: php, laravel

Why am I getting this error. I created a PortfolioController. Then I made a route using this

```
Route::get('portfolio','PortfolioController');
```

So in my controller page I made this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PortfolioController extends Controller
{
  //This only gets exectued when we request /portfolio/Paintings using GET
    public function getPaintings()
    {
      return 'This RESTful controller is working!';
    }
}
```

I get this error when typing in localhost/portfolio/paintings

Answer (score 8):

From the look of your code, it looks like you're trying to setup an [implicit controller route](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers). You're close, but your route definition is a little off. You need to use `controller` instead of `get`:

```
Route::controller('portfolio','PortfolioController');
```

Comment: Actually I am now getting : NotFoundHttpException in Controller.php line 269:
Controller method not found.

Comment: I found the fix to that issue. I just had to install laravelcollective/html through composer, by  going to cmd prompt and typing in 'composer require laravelcollective/html'

Answer (score 2):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

> The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016:
>
> - Implicit controller routes using `Route::controller` have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes file. This will likely be extracted into a package.

You must declare each endpoint now.

Answer (score 2):

try this

`Route::get('portfolio','PortfolioController@getPaintings')`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. To met, this looks like a duplicate of the answer given by Ryuujo

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error when there was a mistake in he file of web.php.

A correct route would like this `Route::get('portfolio','YourController@yourMethod');`

Answer (score 1):

You have to consume a function of the controller instead of using the whole controller class for one request. so laravel doesn't know which of your function to use.

Try using `PortfolioController@index`. or `Route::resource('yourroute','PortfolioController');`

Comment: Because the function of that Controller is just `getPaintings`, so I think to use `PortofolioController@getPaintings`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in routes:

```
Route::resource('portfolio','YourController@yourMethod');
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to explain your function on Route.
example:

```
Route::methods('your-uri','YourController@YourFunction');
```

so you should do this:

```
Route::get('portfolio','PortfolioController@getPaintings');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Route::resource('/portfolio','PortfolioController');
Hope this will work